# Need help or advice on how to iterate a nested loop for collision detection in my 2d directx 9 game

Tags: c++

```
    //=============================================================================
// Handle collisions   //=============================================================================
void Spacewar::collisions()
{
    VECTOR2 collisionVector;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (ship[i].collidesWith(planet, collisionVector))
        {
            // bounce off planet
            ship[i].bounce(collisionVector, planet);
            ship[i].damage(PLANET);

            // if collision between ships
            for (int j = i + 1; j < 10; j++)
            {
                if (ship[i].collidesWith(ship[j], collisionVector))
                {
                    // Bounce off ship
                    ship[i].bounce(collisionVector, ship[j]);
                    ship[i].damage(SHIP);
                    // change the direction of the collisionVector for ship2
                    ship[j].bounce(collisionVector*-1, ship[i]);
                    ship[j].damage(SHIP);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need help with using my collision detection using a nested loop. The ships will collide and bounce off the planet, however, collision isn't detected when the ships themselves collide.

This is DirectX 9 3D apk using C++

Additional Information

```
bool Entity::collidesWith(Entity &ent, VECTOR2 &collisionVector)
{ 
    // if either entity is not active then no collision may occcur
    if (!active || !ent.getActive())    
        return false;

    // If both entities are CIRCLE collision
    if (collisionType == entityNS::CIRCLE && ent.getCollisionType() == entityNS::CIRCLE)
        return collideCircle(ent, collisionVector);
    // If both entities are BOX collision
    if (collisionType == entityNS::BOX && ent.getCollisionType() == entityNS::BOX)
        return collideBox(ent, collisionVector);
    // All other combinations use separating axis test
    // If neither entity uses CIRCLE collision
    if (collisionType != entityNS::CIRCLE && ent.getCollisionType() != entityNS::CIRCLE)
        return collideRotatedBox(ent, collisionVector);
    else    // one of the entities is a circle
        if (collisionType == entityNS::CIRCLE)  // if this entity uses CIRCLE collision
        {
            // Check for collision from other box with our circle
            bool collide = ent.collideRotatedBoxCircle(*this, collisionVector); 
            // Put the collision vector in the proper direction
            collisionVector *= -1;              // reverse collision vector
            return collide;
        }
        else    // the other entity uses CIRCLE collision
            return collideRotatedBoxCircle(ent, collisionVector);
    return false;
}
```

This is the Entity::collidesWith() function that my collision detection uses an an inherited member function in the Spacewar class.  I didn't add this information because Entity::collidesWith() code was never altered.

Anyways, in the original code which had 2 ships individually defined, initialized, drawn, rendered and updated. The collision detection worked.

Original code:

```
//=============================================================================
// Handle collisions
//=============================================================================
void Spacewar::collisions()
{
    VECTOR2 collisionVector;
    // if collision between ship and planet
    if(ship1.collidesWith(planet, collisionVector))
    {
        // bounce off planet
        ship1.bounce(collisionVector, planet);
        ship1.damage(PLANET);
    }
    if(ship2.collidesWith(planet, collisionVector))
    {
        // bounce off planet
        ship2.bounce(collisionVector, planet);
        ship2.damage(PLANET);
    }
    // if collision between ships
    if(ship1.collidesWith(ship2, collisionVector))
    {
        // bounce off ship
        ship1.bounce(collisionVector, ship2);
        ship1.damage(SHIP);
        // change the direction of the collisionVector for ship2
        ship2.bounce(collisionVector*-1, ship1);
        ship2.damage(SHIP);
    }
}
```

The complication with all this is that the assignment in the book said, "Modify the "Planet Collision" example to use an array of 10 ships. (Hint: Use a nested loop when performing collision checks.)

```
for (int i =  0; i < MAX_SHIPS; i++)
{
    if (ships[i].collidesWith(planet, collisionVector))
    {
        // Bounce off planet
        ships[i].bounce(collisionVector, planet);
    }
    // If collision between ships
    // For all other ships
    for (int j = i+1; j<MAX_SHIPS; j++)
    {
        if (ships[i].collidesWith(ships[j], collisionVector))
        {
            // Bounce off ship
```

."

The original code without nested loops and an array of ships worked.

Comment: Your ship collision check is inside the treatment for the planet collision... I guess that is not meant to be. If that does not help, you might want to post you actual `collidesWith` function.

Comment: I realize what you meant now and thanks so much for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I think you accidentally put the collision detection for ships inside the block containing the code for collision for planets.

Try change your code to this:

```
        void Spacewar::collisions()
    {
        VECTOR2 collisionVector;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (ship[i].collidesWith(planet, collisionVector))
            {
                // bounce off planet
                ship[i].bounce(collisionVector, planet);
                ship[i].damage(PLANET);
            }

            // if collision between ships
            for (int j = i + 1; j < 10; j++)
            {
                if (ship[i].collidesWith(ship[j], collisionVector))
                {
                    // Bounce off ship
                    ship[i].bounce(collisionVector, ship[j]);
                    ship[i].damage(SHIP);
                    // change the direction of the collisionVector for ship2
                    ship[j].bounce(collisionVector*-1, ship[i]);
                    ship[j].damage(SHIP);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was following the instructions in the book, which any book is prone to errors, and didn't realize that the didn't put a closing bracket for the if (ship[i].collidesWith(planet, collisionVector)) statement.